# Creating FactoryGirl objects in test database leads to ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have made a separate database for manual testing but have run into the error above when I attempt to create Factories into the database.

Here is the work flow:

```
`rails c test`
`FactoryGirl.create(:reverification_tracker)
`ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
   from /Users/drubio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:715:in `URI'
```

Here is the factory I am attempting to create with its accompanying association:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :reverification_tracker do
    association :account
    message_id 'XYZ0-1234-AB56-67GJ'
    feedback ''
    phase 0
    status 0
    attempts 1
    sent_at DateTime.now.utc
    created_at DateTime.now.utc
    updated_at DateTime.now.utc
 end

FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :account_login do |n|
    "login-#{n}"
  end

factory :account do
  sequence :email do |n|
    "someone#{n}@gmail.com"
  end

  email_confirmation { |account| account.send :email }
  url { Faker::Internet.url }
  login { generate(:account_login) }
  password { Faker::Internet.password }
  password_confirmation { |account| account.send(:password) }
  current_password { |account| account.send(:password) }
  twitter_account 'openhub'
  name { Faker::Name.name + rand(999_999).to_s }
  about_raw { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
  activated_at { Time.current }
  activation_code nil
  country_code 'us'
  email_master true
  email_kudos true
  email_posts true

  association :github_verification
end
```

Why is this happening? On the get go I notice that in my local path directory there are reference folers to `ruby-2.2.3` and `ruby 2.2.0`

Also, you will note that my account factory has a url field on it. I'm using the `faker` gem to create a url for testing. To my knowledge there does not seem to be a problem with that. Additionally, my account model has a `url_format` validation set to `true` with the validation defined like so

```
class UrlFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator


 # With Ruby 2.2, the default URI parser is more forgiving than we want, so use the same trick Rails does in Rack
  # see: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10669
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    valid_url = begin
      @parser ||= defined?(URI::RFC2396_Parser) ? URI::RFC2396_Parser.new : URI
      @parser.parse(value).is_a?(URI::HTTP)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
      false
    end

    record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || I18n.t('accounts.invalid_url_format')) unless valid_url
  end
end
```

However, I am positively certain that this is not the problem either. I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem before. I've seen similar questions with `xhr` on this website but it doesn't exactly line up with what I need. Any insight would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you track it down by trying `rescue URI::InvalidURIError, ArgumentError` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply max, I'm not sure as to where I would insert that `rescue` keyword. Where would you recommend I place that?

Comment: We really need to see the full stacktrace, are you using `pry`?  Type `wtf?` after your error to see more stacktrace and paste that into your question.

Comment: You would add it inside your `UrlFormatValidator#validate_each` method, just add `, ArgumentError` where you are currently rescueing `URI::InvalidURIError`. It would narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: I found the problem. It was an environment variable in the application. `wtf?` revealed it to me. Thanks